# After a refusal (V4.2(a)(c)) proving I have sufficient funds when applying for a UK Standard visit visa

Tags: visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a standard visitor visa to the UK for seven days. I earn £278/month and have been working at the same organization for more than a year. I have saved up enough funds for the trip and I attached bank statements to prove it. The ECO refused my visa stating:

> I note that you stated that your trip to the UK will cost you £1100, this is approximately 4 times your monthly income. I do not find it credible that you spend this amount on a trip.

I am a single woman, with no financial responsibilities and I saved up for this trip because I really wanted to visit the UK.

How do I prove to the ECO and the authorities that spending £1,100 for my trip wouldn't have caused me any financial harm neither would I have had to access UK government funds?

[image: image of the refusal]

Another concern of mine is that if I reapply without the partial funding of my father or get sponsored by a different person, does the amount given by my father previously cause hindrance in my visa application?

Won't they still reject it on the basis of my pay being too insignificant?

Comment: I agree with the ECO that it is hard to believe that you'd spend 4 times your monthly salary on a trip. Having said that, your situation could be unique and different. The nest time you apply, make it a point to explain to the ECO why you think it would not cause you any financial constraints, show proof of family funds or things of that sort.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, nice one. good call sir!  Something's terribly wrong. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @GayotFow Perhaps we've found the one ECO in the world who can't write very well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was taken up on chat and I will provide a summary of what transpired...

- The OP should complain about the poor quality of the refusal notice.
  That's a high priority.
- Based upon some additional background info the OP provided, it became
  evident that the **REAL** reason for her refusal was she failed to
  establish a credible premise for her visit.  She also didn't
  establish why a single woman of marriageable age wants to visit the
  UK.  Doing that is important in South Asia. I understand this point may be contentious with some, but personal circumstances make up an important part of the decision.
- The refusal notice focuses entirely on technical points none of which
  map in to her personal circumstances.  Possibly a paragraph or two got accidentally deleted by the assistant? She needs to get a proper
  refusal notice and that should be part of her complaint.
- For the OP's premise to work, she needs to explain the
  disproportionate expense she is taking on. Personal enrichment? Peer
  status? Romance? Literacy? Shopping? What does she expect to gain by spending so much for a 7 day
  trip?
- The OP needs to explain the irregular cash flows in her bank
  statements.
- The OP needs to explain why her father is sponsoring her.
- The OP needs to read all of the questions/answers in [this link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds).

The OP will apply again in about a month, and while preparing her application will come here with *highly focused* and *very clear* questions.  The complete chat transcript is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here).

Answer (score 0):

As per what I've read above..you should only apply again if your current circumstances change drastically otherwise whatever documents and country ties you show wouldn't mean much to the visa officer. 
A drastic change could be

> getting married 
>   becoming the owner of a property that you haven't already told them about
>   starting a business and maintaining a good statement

See for the amount that you have mentioned as monthly income the visa officer is bound to think that you might visit UK to find a job and assuming that you are not married and don't have enough savings or any property in your name, creates further doubt that you might not return.

Don't apply for at least 6 months.